# Cannot share a flash video on Facebook news feed to play inline

Tags: facebook, flash

I used opengraph tag to embed a flash player on Facebook news feed, it worked well before April 2014. I don't know why now it is not working any more. The embed tag as sample below:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sitename" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image url" />
<meta property="og:video" content="flash.swf player url" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="246" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

I have been searching on Google a lot but still cannot find the result. Does FB changes something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Bug  Status: Assigned  please check :    https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1503212169899736/

You can  work around  this by hosting your swf player on Amazon S3 servers . it works for me .

I have the same problem since 21 APR ,  i tried everything

Try the Debug tool : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=
and check if your site enabled  -- Video embedding on Facebook enabled --

Comment: I saw the same status: Video status Video embedding on Facebook enabled. But the video didn't play inline anymore.

Comment: Thank Zaher, it is fixed @ https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1503212169899736/